# SQL UPDATE on the same table with WHERE

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I have the following table and I want to fill up the empty values of the name column with the same value of the name where id_lang=2.
Any idea of what the sql query should be?

| id_product | id_lang | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | - |
| 1 | 2 | name1 |
| 2 | 1 | - |
| 2 | 2 | name2 |
| 3 | 1 | - |
| 3 | 2 | name3 |
| 4 | 1 | - |
| 4 | 2 | name4 |

Comment: Please, show what did you try so far. And tag your DBMS.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

One general approach which should work uses a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET name = (SELECT name FROM yourTable t2
            WHERE t2.id_product = t1.id_product AND t2.id_lang = 2)
WHERE
    name IS NULL;
```

Comment: Although it looks that's the right approach I get a SQL error and still, I'm not able to find the correct syntax.


#1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery: `UPDATE table SET name = (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table WHERE id_lang = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

In a query, you can simply use window function:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(name,
                max(case when id_lang = 2 then name end) over (partition by id_product)
               ) as imputed_name
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that `-` really means `NULL`.  If it is a string, the above can be tweaked to use `CASE`.

You can easily do this in an `update` as well, if you want to change the data in the table.  However, the best way to do that depends on the database.